# How to allow a user to take a video and display it in a viewcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, storyboard, video-capture

I am working on an app and would like to give the user an option to record a video and then have that video displayed in a view controller. I am very new to programming and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an image to give you an idea of what I mean.

(IMAGE 1)- http://tinypic.com/r/t7gzeb/8

Answer (score 0):

How about using GPUImage?
You can use AVFoundation.framework, but to use GPUImage is easier.
You can use below code to display capturing video, and can save video to use GPUImageMovieWriter.

```
self.videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
self.videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
self.videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = YES;

GPUImageSepiaFilter *filter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
[self.videoCamera addTarget:filter];

GPUImageView *filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
[self.view addSubview:filterView];
[filter addTarget:filterView];

[self.videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Comment: Did you add GPUImage static library from [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)?

Comment: Yes I used cocoapods to add it

Comment: I created and uploaded sample project here.
Please try this.
https://github.com/nerd0geek1/GPUImageMovieRecorderSample